# Cannot start ASP.NET application (Localhost did not started...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing some page and until now was everything fine, but now, I want to check some changes but localhost didn´t start.
Only one thing that will happen is an added tab in a browser with connection lost.

Here´s screenshot :

[image: After clicking start nothink will happen]

Comment: Maybe IIS stopped. You check IIS and start it.

Comment: It may sounds bad, but how can i check it ?

Comment: You open Internet Information Services.  You see Start, Stop, Restart buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that restart helped.

Service IIS has been invalid...